# CMD appears not to recognize variables

Tags: cmd, set, session-variables

CMD does not appear to be recognizing any variable I store using SET. If I run this batch file:

```
@ECHO off
SET /P name = What is your name? 
ECHO %name%
PAUSE
ECHO on
```

I get the following output:

```
What is your name? steven
ECHO is off.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

When I run line 2 and then line 3 from the command prompt, it just prints:

```
%name%
```

Do I have something configured incorrectly? Am I correct in thinking that line 2 should create a session variable that should be recognized in line 3?

I searched, but I could only find answers related to variable expansion within IF blocks. This is happening to me outside any IF/FOR/etc blocks.

This is Windows 7, by the way. I'm not sure how much cmd changes from one version of Windows to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must not be any spaces around the equal sign in the `set` instruction. Change this

```
SET /P name = What is your name?
```

into this

```
SET /P name=What is your name?
```

and your problem will disappear.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think to check that. I knew it was sensitive to white space, but I didn't know it was that sensitive.

Thank you for the quick response. Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

since I can not add any comments yet I have to post a new answer.  The information:

"There must not be any spaces around the equal sign in the set instruction."

is only partly correct. To be exact it should say: the equal sign must follow directly after the variable name (in sricks3's case without a space). Whatever comes after the equal sign will be used as input-prompt for the variable including any spaces, so the following code will work as well:

```
SET /P name= What is your name?
```